# Netplan: how do I apply specific configuration YAML file

Tags: networking, netplan

Consider multiple netplan configuration YAML files:

```
/etc/netplan/config0.yaml
/etc/netplan/config1.yaml
```

How to pass to «netplan apply» name of the configuration YAML file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not.  The netplan configuration is the union of all the yaml files in the config directory; `netplan apply` calculates the complete configuration based on this set of files and renders it for passing to the backend.  It is therefore invalid to ask `netplan apply` to apply only the config from *one* of these files, because any of the other configuration files might contain settings that modify the configuration of the interfaces listed in your one file, and the only way netplan knows whether this is the case is by loading all of the files together.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: "You do not" correctly: "you can not". And contrary the answer, yes it would be possible, it is just not developed into the tool.