# Netplan config files overwriting each other

Tags: files, configuration, netplan

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167381/netplan-how-do-i-apply-specific-configuration-yaml-file) the applicable netplan config is the union of all config files.

If two config files configure the same interface differently or otherwise have conflicting information, which config is applied in the end? The one with the alphabetically last filename? e.g. if you have 00-config.yaml and 01-config.yaml, would the properties in 01-config.yaml be used?

Answer (score 7):

The rules for this are documented in `man netplan-generate`:

> If there are files with different names, then they are considered in lexicographical order - regardless of the  directory they  are  in.   Later files add to or override earlier files.  For example, `/run/netplan/10-foo.yaml` would be updated by `/lib/netplan/20-abc.yaml`.
>
> If you have two files with the same key/setting, the following rules apply:
>
> - If the values are YAML boolean or scalar values (numbers and strings) the old value is overwritten by the new value.
> - If the values are sequences, the sequences are concatenated - the new values are appended to the old list.
> - If the values are mappings, netplan will examine the elements of the mappings in turn using these rules.

Comment: Thanks. That clears it up.